# How to regain script interactivity when `... | bash` best practices?

Tags: bash, pipe, stdin, exec, interactive

Let's say we have a simple script named `question`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

read -rp "What's your name?" ans

echo "Your name is $ans"
```

Let's use `cat` for our example

```
cat question | bash
```

We feed the content of the script file to the standard input of Bash and execute it as a command. When executed the standard input of bash is used, so nothing past the pipe is possible to be fed to standard in, unless put before the pipe.

To mitigate this, an option is to download the content of the script file first pass it to the shell and only then execute it.

```
bash -c "$(cat ./question)"
```

Another option I found for the syntax `... | bash` is that in the script, if we replace the current process with a new one where the stdin is redirected from the terminal, wrapped in a subshell it works, as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

(
 exec < /dev/tty

 read -rp "What's your name?" ans

 echo "Your name is $ans"
)
```

I wonder what other options exist there or what'd be the best practice.

Comment: Can you give an example of why you would ever want to do this? Feeding scripts to bash with `cat script | bash` is rarely a good idea, using `read` to populate variables instead of passing them as command line arguments is also rarely a good idea (both of these _can_ be the right thing to do sometimes, just not often), so the combination of what you are describing seems strange. Can you give a specific example of what you are trying to do and why this is the right approach for it?

Comment: Side note: `bash -c "$(cat ./question)"` looks unnecessarily complicated. Since you have the regular file, you can as well tell bash to read it directly: `bash ./question`.

Comment: @terdon hypothetically looking into the horrors of curl pipe scripts

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Sure, I agree. Although the idea is to explore the topic of regaining script interactivity on `... | bash`. While not a good practice, but as an exercise to understand possibilities better.

Comment: @punkbit well, that's kinda why you never download stuff and pipe to a shell. That is the mother of all security threats.

Comment: One option to execute a script and stay interactive is `bash --init-file file.sh`. In this case, the shell reads `file.sh` rather than `~/.bashrc` at the beginning. One drawback could be that the script is executed in an interactive shell environment which may not be desirable. Also you won't have configurations specified in `~/.bashrc`.